# How to add values in nested hash in ruby's way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is a nested hash. We want to add all the value of "subtotal" together in ruby's way. Please be noted that the key of "0" and "1342119042142" could be any other unknown strings (number of keys is at least one. Could be more than one) when performing the addition.

```
{"0"=>{"lease_item_id"=>"3",
 "subtotal"=>"100"},
 "1342119042142"=>{"lease_item_id"=>"1",
 "subtotal"=>"100",
 "_destroy"=>"false"}}}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "ruby's way" is as meaningless as "pythonic" for Python. For every language one should use the most idiomatic and powerful resources that it offers, that's assumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

set up hash:

```
s = {"0"=>{"lease_item_id"=>"3", "subtotal"=>"100"},
     "1342119042142"=>{"lease_item_id"=>"1", "subtotal"=>"100","_destroy"=>"false"}}
```

calculate total:

```
total = s.inject(0) { |i, j| i + j.last["subtotal"].to_i}
```

Explanation: Look [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) for documentation. Basically `inject` is given an initial value (in the above code it is 0) and it passes the given value to the given block, where it gets set to what is returned from the block in each iteration. So in the above code, initially it is 0, on the first iteration it is set to `0 + 100` and now is equal to 100, and on the second [and final] iteration it is set to `100 + 100`, 200.

Comment: `j` is an Array because you're iterating over a Hash and that always gives you the key/value pairs. You could `{ |i,(k,v)| ... }` and use `v` instead. And there's no need for `+=` as `inject` feeds the block's value back in as `i` in the next iteration: `{ |i,(k,v)| i + v['subtotal'].to_i }`.

Comment: @mikhailvs & mu is too short, could you explain how the inject works here or point to some document? I saw some amazing use of inject and tried to understand. But the logic behind it is still not clear to me. Thanks.

Comment: `i`, `j` are too generic, variable names should be descriptive. Better: `{ |acc, (key, attrs)| acc + attrs["subtotal"].to_i }`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming h is your hash and the subtotal can be decimal value:

```
h.values.sum{|x| x['subtotal'].to_f}
```

Comment: There is no method `sum` for arrays in ruby.

Comment: The question has tag [ruby-on-rails], sum is added by activesupport core extensions for Enumerable: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum

Comment: However, OP explicitly says he wants the answer "in ruby's way"

Comment: In rails console, the above works. I should mention both ruby or rails' way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {"0"=>{"lease_item_id"=>"3", "subtotal"=>"100"}, "1342119042142"=>{"lease_item_id"=>"1", "subtotal"=>"100", "_destroy"=>"false"}} 

sum = hash.values.reduce(0){|sum,inner| sum + inner["subtotal"].to_i }
```